# Installing Elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on an app that, unfortunately, only works with Elasticsearch 1.7, but I can't find it anywhere (for Mac). [This](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-7-0) page doesn't appear to have a download link. I previously installed it via Homebrew, but now, the oldest version available is 2.4, and for some reason, my copy stopped working and I've since uninstalled it (not knowing it was no longer available).

I still have it installed and working on a different machine–is it possible to manually copy over and link the necessary files? Any help is really appreciated!

EDIT: Are [These](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/setup-repositories.html) the steps I should be following or is this for servers only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this page has a download link: https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.0.zip
You don't need a separate link for Mac since ElasticSearch in written on Java, so you just need JRE to run it.
After you unzip it you should be able to run it like this:

```
cd bin
./elasticsearch
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I'm used to starting/stopping Elasticsearch through Homebrew–where should I store these files and do I simply run this same command each time? Thanks again

Comment: You are not restricted to a particular folder. As for simplified starting/stopping - you can add you elasticsearch/bin path to `$PATH` environment variable. Take a look at this example https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-on-mac-os-x/